# What primer should we use on a previously painted concrete wall?

Tags: concrete, paint, primer

We are preparing to prime and paint over previously painted interior concrete walls. The walls have oil residue (from an oil furnace) that is embedded in the rough surface and we were unable to fully clean it off.  What primer should we use to create both a good bond for the topcoat and prevent bleed-through of the oil residue?

Answer (score 1):

You do not need to prime a previously painted concrete surface. The oil residue will cause adhesion problems with any surface coating, including "problem surface" primers. You need to use a detergent (or TSP) and warm water solution with a scrub brush and wash the oil residue off of the walls, then rinse clean. Then apply a high quality paint with top of the line applicators.

Answer (score 0):

Use an alkaline cleanser to get the hydrocarbon (oil) stains out. Cleaners and degreasers are available from many sources (use google).